# Is it possible to paste a range into a range using cell index reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA but I'm trying to copy a range from one workbook into another.

Within the macro I am already exporting a file with a variable in the file name that generates a version number - the version number corresponds to the column I want to copy the data into, hence the need to use `range(cells())` approach. `DestCol` returns the column number I want to paste into no problem.

I have tried a load of suggestions I've found online but just can't get it to work, including referencing the workbook with the range, paste special etc.

eg. `Workbooks().Worksheets().Range(Workbooks().Worksheets().Cells(2,2))`

Any help is much appreciated.

Stepping through the macro I can see the 'Cells...' part has the message "Application-defined or Object-Defined error"

```vb
Workbooks("adjuster.xlsm").Worksheets("Exp_build").Range("C1:C5000").Copy
    
Workbooks(FN).Worksheets("Log").Range(Cells(2, DestCol)).PasteSpecial Paste:=x1PasteValues
```

Comment: Yes but when refering to one cell the `Range(` is not needed: `Workbooks(FN).Worksheets("Log").Cells(2, DestCol).PasteSpecial ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried removing the `range(` and still no luck.

Comment: did you also remove the extra `)`?  What is `FN`?  How is it declared and what is its value?

Comment: Also what is the value of `DestCol`

Comment: Yep removed the extra `)`.

Comment: FN is the name of a workbook and I've double checked its giving the right vale in this case its: `Change Log.xlsm'

DestCol changes and is built off a file version number that I'm exporting earlier in the code. it is always an integer.

Comment: are you sure both have what you would expect at the time of the error?  and what error are you getting now?

Comment: Sorry finally just to add it works fine if I use a standard range reference eg `("C3")` but I need to get it working with column index numbers to output what I need!

Comment: You will need to show more code.  We will need a [mcve].  Otherwise we can only guess.  My last guess is the `DestCol` is `0` when it errors.

Comment: Thought That might be the case, I will tidy the whole lot up and get an example uploaded here.

Comment: `x1PasteValues` => `xlPasteValues`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, completely missed that typo thanks GSerg although I had another issue: I had `DestCol` as a string variable where it should be as `Long`. Sure you would have picked it up if I'd put more code here in the first place...